# Transfer from one 4-year college to another 4-year college

Tags: collegescorecard

I am trying to understand how students who transfer from one four-year college to another are counted in earnings data--I understand they are counted by their original institution, but do they also show up in earnings data for the institution that they transfer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forwarded your question on to those familiar with the data and this was their response:

> Earnings for the student would be counted at both institutions if they
>   were federally aided at both institutions. If a student was aided at
>   the original school, then transfers and doesn’t receive Title IV aid
>   at the new school, they would not be identified at the new school
>   through the cohort construction process.  The end of page 36 and top
>   of page 37 in the data [Documentation Report](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/FullDataDocumentation.pdf) provide more
>   information on this topic.